# Responsive element transition

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

Hi I don't know how to solve this...

I want the element marked with a red rectangle in the images to move depending on the size of the screen ALIGNED to the containers below ALL THE TIME. I'm making a responsive website with the different media screen instances but I want to be sure that this element keeps in the same alignment all the time. How do I do that? No JS please.

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/58399/669844960fdd9761084f64bae5d29112

Comment: Please post the relevant code *here*.

Comment: What does "aligned to the containers below" mean?

Comment: @isherwood he means the box in red should remain within the bounds of the red line on the right (which is the bound of the content below)

Comment: Ah. I hadn't scrolled right to see that line. Thanks. Some clarification is still needed, along with some code. What should happen when there's not enough space between the red line and the search box for the title box, for example?

Answer (score 0):

since you haven't provided any code for what you have so far its difficult to help you. However, I think I understand what you need and you need to specify some width constraints to accomplish this:

you will need a container inside the header that will have the same width as the content below. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/0eag38e0/) is a working fiddle

```
css {
 width: X%; 
}
```

Comment: Please take a look and let me know https://www.amstardmc.com/responsive/indexwide.html